# How to handle getOffers request pagination on Mirakl PHP SDK for sellers?

Tags: php, pagination, sdk

I took care to read the documentation of the Mirakl PHP SDK, but I am facing an issue regarding the use of the API OF21: List offers of a shop. I use the PHP SDK in version 1.18.1

I want to retrieve all the offers from my shop (there are around 700) to store them once a day in a database on my side (and thus not systematically call the marketplace API).
In particular, I need to access the *Offers > Active* and *Offers > Inactivity_reasons* information that is not found in the API OF51 Get offers CSV file.

I'm using the PHP SDK so I understand there is a limit to the number of results returned, but I don't see a way to handle pagination when using the [SDK getOffers function](https://github.com/mirakl/sdk-php-shop/blob/master/src/Mirakl/MMP/Shop/Request/Offer/GetOffersRequest.php)

How to proceed to be able to retrieve and store on my side the list of all the offers via this API OF21, because I don't see anything about the possibility of using pagination in the getOffers function (expected parameters in particular)?

Thank you for your help.

For reference, here's, in a simplified way, what I was headed for

````
$api = new ShopApiClient($apiUrl, $apiKey, $shopId);

function fetchAllOffers(ShopApiClient $api, $shopId) {
    $allOffers = [];
    $offset = 0;
    $max = 100; // Max query results

    $totalOffersCount = 0; // Initialiser à 0
    do {
        $request = new GetOffersRequest($shopId);
        $request->set('max', $max);
        $request->set('offset', $offset);
    
        $promise = $api->async()->getOffers($request);
        $response = $promise->wait();
    
        // Read and json_decode the response
        $body = (string) $response->getBody();
        $data = json_decode($body, true);
        
        // Get the total offers count
        $totalOffersCount = $data['total_count'] ?? 0;

        $offers = $data['offers'] ?? [];
    
        $allOffers = array_merge($allOffers, $offers);
        $offset += $max;
    
    } while (count($allOffers) < $totalOffersCount);

    return $allOffers;
}

function displayOffers($allOffers) {
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr><th>SKU</th></tr>';

    foreach ($allOffers as $offer) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $offer['product_sku'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

try {
    $allOffers = fetchAllOffers($api, $shopId);
    displayOffers($allOffers);
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    echo 'Error : ' . $e->getMessage();
}```
````

Comment: _"here's, in a simplified way, what I was headed for"_ - can you explain what that actually means? It looks like you already attempted to call methods to set a `max` and an `offset` parameter for the request - so did those not _work_ as expected, or does what you're saying mean they don't actually _exist_, but are how you would imagine this should work, and you are now looking for the real methods to use, or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED :** I've got an answer on the github Mirakl SDK repo from user amarie75 thanks to him/her. Here is the answer that solved my problem :

> The problem is the method set() who doesn't exist on request objects.
> You should use setMax() and setOffset() methods. In your exemple, I
> think you retrieve the 10 first offers 7 or 8 times.
>
> Here another way to write your exemple:

```
$api = new ShopApiClient($apiUrl, $apiKey, $shopId);

function fetchAllOffers(ShopApiClient $api, $shopId) {
    $allOffers = [];
    $offset = 0;
    $max = 100; // Max query results

    $totalOffersCount = 0; // Initialiser à 0
    do {
        $request = new GetOffersRequest($shopId);
        $request->setMax($max);
        $request->setOffset($offset);
    
        $response = $api->getOffers($request);
        
        // Get the total offers count
        $totalOffersCount = $response->getTotalCount();

        $offers = $response->getItems();
    
        $allOffers = array_merge($allOffers, $offers);
        $offset += $max;
    
    } while (count($allOffers) < $totalOffersCount);

    return $allOffers;
}

function displayOffers($allOffers) {
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr><th>SKU</th></tr>';

    foreach ($allOffers as $offer) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $offer->getSku() . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

try {
    $allOffers = fetchAllOffers($api, $shopId);
    displayOffers($allOffers);
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    echo 'Error : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```